# Bash script with multiline heredoc doesn't output anything

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I'm writing a script to send SQL output in mail, but it is not executing successfully and is not generating the output I want.

The query generates two columns with multiple rows. How can I generate the output in table format as below?

[image: table with columns listname | last received]

Below is my code:

```bah
#!/bin/bash

ORACLE_HOME= **PATH
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export PATH
TNS_ADMIN= ** PATH
export TNS_ADMIN


today=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)

output=$(sqlplus -S user/pass@service <<EOF
set heading off;
SELECT distinct list_name ,max(captured_dttm) as Last_received FROM db.table1
group by list_name having  max(captured_dttm) <= trunc(sysdate - interval '2' hour);
EOF)

if [ -z "$output" ];
then
echo"its fine"
exit
else

echo "
Dear All,

Kindly check we've not received the list for last 2 hour : $output
Regards,
Team" | mailx -S smtp=XX.XX.X.XX:XX -s "URGENT! Please check list FOR $today"   user@abc.com
fi
```

Comment: There are a bunch of spacing errors here. You can't put spaces around the `=` in an assignment (so use `ORACLE_HOME=**PATH` instead of `ORACLE_HOME= **PATH`, except I'm pretty sure that's wrong too because I think it's supposed to be an actual path). Also, you need a space between `echo` and what it's supposed to print.

Comment: Give [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) a try. In this case it will pinpoint the problem and says "[Add a linefeed](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1119) between end token and terminating ')'."

Answer (score 4):

When using a here document, the closing string can't be followed by anything but a newline. Move the closing parenthesis to the next line:

```
output=$(sqlplus -S user/pass@service <<EOF
...
EOF
)
```